# Vectorize some matlab code

Tags: matlab

I have the following matlab code which i want to write with no for loop:
The code takes assings values that meet a certain condition to a sparse matrix.
II, JJ are the sparse matrix indexes.

```
    all_tanh_bits = ones(1, NUMBER_OF_EQ);
    %Calculating each equation multipicative factor.
    for index = 1 : length(II)
        all_tanh_bits(II(index)) = (all_tanh_bits(II(index)) * ...
            tanh(messages_matrix(II(index), JJ(index))/2));
    end

    for index = 1 : length(II)
        %not_relevant_mul is the elemnt to divide - so the
        %current node only uses other message nodes for
        %calculating the llr.
        not_relevant_mul = tanh(messages_matrix(II(index),  ...
                                                JJ(index)) / 2);

        check_matrix_mul = all_tanh_bits(II(index)) / not_relevant_mul;
        check_matrix(II(index), JJ(index)) = ...
            log((1 + check_matrix_mul) / (1 - check_matrix_mul));
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The first for loop can be vectorized as follows. The second one can be done similarly.

```
 all_tanh_bits(II) = all_tanh_bits(II) .* tanh(messages_matrix(sub2ind(size(message_matrix), II, JJ))/2);
```

Comment: What about the other for loop?

Comment: Well, if you understand what I wrote for the first one, then it's straightforward to vectorize the second one using `./`. But by looking at your first loop again, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here - you multiply something by 1?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it doesn't seem to be working:/ Can you give me some other solution. I get en error that the dimension don't agree.